# How do I change the ILazyLoader implementation in Entity Framework Core 2.2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I created an ASP.NET Core 2.2 Application, in `Startup.cs` I have this:

```
services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer();
services.AddScoped<ILazyLoader, MyLazyLoader>();

services.AddDbContext<ModelContext>(builder =>
{
    builder.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
    builder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
    var options = builder.Options;
    services.AddSingleton(options);
});
```

But the lazyloader is not changed, what do I need to change do make this change?

Comment: Register your implementation *after* calling `AddDbContext`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the first two lines

```
services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer();
services.AddScoped<ILazyLoader, MyLazyLoader>();
```

and setup the EFC related stuff inside `AddDbContext` builder action.

`builder.UseSqlServer` will do internally `AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()`, and to *replace* the `ILazyLoader` *service*, use - well, `ReplaceService` method:

```
services.AddDbContext<ModelContext>(builder =>
{
    builder.ReplaceService<ILazyLoader, MyLazyLoader>();
    // ...
});
```